# error "%s: invalid identifier" occurs when I create a table in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle

when I create a table like this:

```
create table DBDI_HIREDETAIL(
HireID int not null,
EquipID int not null,
Quantity int,
TotalFee float,
Comment varchar(200)
);
```

The error occurs like this:

> Error at Command Line:  "TotalFee float"
>   Error report:
>   SQL Error: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

I don't understand why my code has an error, it seems to be fine.

Comment: @Satya, yup: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF50981

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`COMMENT` is a reserved word in Oracle; it's used for adding [comments](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_4009.htm#SQLRF01109) to the data dictionary. You should avoid using this as a column name.

```
SQL> create table a ( comment number );
create table a ( comment number )
                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
```

If you *really* want to use this column name you're have to quote it, i.e. `"COMMENT"`:

```
SQL> create table a ( "COMMENT" number );

Table created.
```

I would recommend you not doing this as you have to quote the column everywhere.

Comment: thank you so much , it works :), I'm a newbie in Oracle DB and I tried to include the symbol "[ ]" as "[Comment]" because I though that it sames as MS sql server but it didn't work.

Comment: No problem @user1712088! Your life will be a lot easier if you come up with a different name for the column though rather than quoting the column name. If you quote it you have to ensure that it is identical each time; you'll save yourself a lot of hassle in the longer run if you call it `comments` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

That's because COMMENT is a reserved word in SQL - use another column name (like HIREDETAIL_COMMENT) instead:

```
create table DBDI_HIREDETAIL(
  HireID int not null,
  EquipID int not null,
  Quantity int,
  TotalFee float,
  HireDetail_Comment varchar(200)
);
```